# Why the interior of $\mathbb{Q}$ in $\mathbb{R}$ is empty?

Tags: calculus, general-topology, metric-spaces

I don't understand why the interior of $\mathbb{Q}$ in $\mathbb{R}$ is empty, since, for every ball with the center being a rational number, given an $\epsilon>0$, I can find an infinite sequence of rational numbers that approach this point. For example, take $\frac{1}{2}$. The sequence $\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{n}$ can be made as close as I want to the number $\frac{1}{2}$, therefore I can always have open balls with center $\frac{1}{2}$ such that there are rationals inside it.

Comment: there's a good explanation [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/224980/interior-set-of-rationals-confused)

Comment: A open ball is **uncountable**, where as the rationals are countable. Hence $\Bbb Q$ cannot possible contain any open ball.

Comment: Check the def'n of Interior.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It doesn’t matter that there are rationals inside the ball: what matters is that your open ball is not a subset of $\Bbb Q$. In order for $\Bbb Q$ to be open in $\Bbb R$, for each $q\in\Bbb Q$ there would have to be an open ball $B(q,\epsilon)$ about $q$ such that $B(q,\epsilon)\subseteq\Bbb Q$, and that is *never* the case: every open interval in $\Bbb R$ contains irrational numbers.

Comment: but why $0$ in $\{0,1,1/2,...,1/n\}$ is isolated?

Comment: hmmm, I understood. $\mathbb{Q}$ has no isolated points in $\mathbb{R}$ because any open subset is not contained in $\mathbb{Q}$, because there are irrationals between the rationals. Now, for the set in my comment above, any subset is contained in it.

Comment: @Guerlando: Do you mean the finite set with $n+1$ elements, or did you mean $\{0\}\cup\left\{\frac1n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\right\}$?

Comment: If I recall correctly, $0$ is not an isolation point of $A=\{1/n: n\in \mathbb{Z}^+\}$ nor is it an isolated point of $A\cup \{0\}$. For any neighborhood of $0$ has to contain some $1/n$. However, It would be an isolated point of the finite set $\{0,1,1/2,\dotsc, 1/n\}$ because you can find some neighborhood that misses all of $1,\dotsc,1/n$, and its a finite set!

Comment: @LoveTooNap29: It’s not a point of your set $A$ at all. The rest of what you say is correct and is why I asked the OP whether he meant what he wrote, or whether he really meant your $\{0\}\cup A$.

Comment: Taking advantage of the discussion, I have another question: what about the interior of $Q$ in $Q$? I Always have doubts about it.

Comment: @CletoPereira (very belatedly): For any space $X$ the set $X$ is open, so it is its own interior. In particular, $\Bbb Q$ is an open set in the space $\Bbb Q$, so its interior in that space is $\Bbb Q$.

Answer (score 5):

For $x$ to be an *interior point*, it is not enough that there exist **some** rational in the ball around $x$, the definition of interior point require that there is some ball that **every** points in it are rational.

Hint: Can you see that your proposed construction of the ball **always** contain some irrational points?

Comment: Taking advantage of the discussion, I have another question: what about the interior of $Q$ in $Q$? I Always have doubts about it.

Comment: @CletoPereira The interior of $\Bbb Q$ in $\Bbb Q$ is itself.

Answer (score 3):

Let $x\in\mathbb{Q}$ Consider any open ball $\mathbb{B}(x,r)$ irrespective of how small you choose the radius $r$ the open ball $\mathbb{B}(x,r)\not\subset\mathbb{Q}$.Because between any two rations there are infinitely many irrations. That is why $int\mathbb{Q}=\phi$ in$\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 0):

It is an immediate consequence of Baire's category theorem. Every singleton $\{q\}$ with $q$ rational number is a closed set with empty interior, therefore also the union of all these singletons, i.e., $\mathbb{Q}$, has empty interior.